# Stronger estimates for dynamical analogue of a sum of multiplicative order and primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-dynamics

Let $a$ be a positive integer and $\mathrm{ord}_{p}(a)$ denote the multiplicative order of $a$ modulo $p.$ We know by a result of Murty, Silverman and Rosen that the sum $$\sum_{p~\text{prime}} \frac{\log p}{p \operatorname{ord}_p(a)^\epsilon}
\le \log\log a + \frac{2}{\epsilon} + C.$$
The dynamical analogue of the above sum for orbits of polynomials of the form $$\mathcal{O}_{\varphi}(\alpha)= \{\alpha, \varphi(\alpha), \varphi^{2}(\alpha)\ldots \}$$ for a polynomial $\varphi$ and point $\alpha$  has been considered by Silverman in his [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.1505) and it states that sum $$\sum_{p~\text{prime}} \frac{\log p}{p \cdot e^{s\cdot m_{p}^{\lambda}}}
\le \frac{C}{s^{1/\lambda}}$$ for all $s> 0$  and $\lambda\ge 1$ where $m_{p}$ denotes the size of orbit modulo $p.$

Do we have any stronger estimates like the first sum  in the case when $\varphi\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}$ for the above sum?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any references in literature regarding this?